# Function does not run without element[index -1]

Tags: javascript, function, indexing

First of all, I'm sorry for the inappropriate title.
So I have a code here for a slider, It's copied from w3schools.com and I understand most of the code beside the last line of code from the `showSlides` function.
`slides[slideIndex-1].style.display='block';`

Why if I replace `slideIndex-1` with 0 or 1 the function does not work anymore.
I have no idea about the use of that, but if it isn't there, the function does not work. (I know the slideIndex is the index of my image).
Why instead of that code I can't use `slides[0].style.display='block';`

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
 <!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

So here is the link from the source  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: Computers commonly start counting at 0. Thus three slides means you have slides #0, #1 and #2. Whoever wrote that code decided to start counting at 1 though, so the slides are now numbered #1, #2 and #3. Which means when the user decides to activate slide x, the computer actually needs to display slide x - 1. This is done setting its `style.display` to `"block"`. Using a 1-based index internally is another fine example why people shouldn't use w3schools. It's bad, it'll always be bad, and it needs to die, badly.

Comment: Can you specify how exactly you are trying to use `slides[0].style.display='block';`? Are you doing it inside the `showSlides()` function? The `slides` array exists only inside that function. You can show a specific slide by calling that function: `showSlides(1);`

Comment: I was trying to wrote this exactly where it is ,for me the logic is :by default i want the slide[0] to display as a block.

Comment: @Chris G you can post the answer to give you that green checkmark if you want

Comment: If anyone knows how to make this function work but with the slides starting from #0 ,please answer

Comment: Showing the first slide by default is accomplished by the `showSlides(slideIndex);` call in the 2nd line. `slideIndex` is 1 in the beginning, so the code initially ends up setting the first slide to be visible. Later, when the function is called again, `slideIndex` will have changed, and that line near the end will display the according slide. The code isn't broken, but the change you wanted to do due to not understanding how it works will break the function, because `slides[0].style.display='block';` will only ever show the first slide, no matter which arrow or dot you click.

Comment: I have no idea why you want to change the code in the first place? Does it not work for you as is? The fact that it's badly written code doesn't mean it won't work as intended.

Comment: i tried using 'slides[slideIndex].style.display='block' and it works but after the #1,#2,#3 images are displayed then I see a blank page, also if you want the checkmark you can post an answer, you helped a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Here's a zero-based solution: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/p6uqmh3d/